# How to assign multiple dafult values in SQL Query for multiple default assigned colums

Tags: mysql, database

```
create table ints (val1 int not null defalut 10,val2 int not null dafult 20);

insert into ints values();

Output is 10,20..OK
```

But if i explicity pass value to one column then insert will not work

```
insert into ints values(99,) ;
```

INSERT FAILS

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

you should specify the column that you are inserting the value into

```
insert into ints(val1) values(99);
```

Read this [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) for insert syntax

UPDATE:

Since you want the default for var1, var2 and var3, you just have to specify the value for var4

```
insert into ints(var4) values(99);
```

or

```
insert into ints(var1, var2, var3, var4) values(10, 20, "DEFAULT", 99)
```

Its as simple as, specify the column names for which you want to insert values in the same order

Comment: if i add 2 more columns to above exapmle.....var3 varchar not null default 'DEFAULT' and var4 int not null. How should i insert for output to be {10,20,'DEFAULT',99}

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert into all columns it's not need to specify columns name but you have to specify columns if not to want insert into all  columns

```
insert into ints(val1) values(99)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what columns the values you **do** give apply to:

```
insert into ints (val1) values(99)
```